# Android Studio: Camera Intent not showing The Camera

Tags: android

I am trying to open the camera then display to the image view after capture. but unfortunately it doesn't display the camera.

also I noticed that startActivityForResult is crossed out and it says deprecated.

Is there anything wrong with this code?

here is my code so far

```
private void launchCameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ClientInformation.this, ImagePickerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_IMAGE_PICKER_OPTION, ImagePickerActivity.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // setting aspect ratio
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_LOCK_ASPECT_RATIO, true);
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_ASPECT_RATIO_X, 1); // 16x9, 1x1, 3:4, 3:2
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_ASPECT_RATIO_Y, 1);

    // setting maximum bitmap width and height
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_SET_BITMAP_MAX_WIDTH_HEIGHT, true);
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_BITMAP_MAX_WIDTH, 1000);
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_BITMAP_MAX_HEIGHT, 1000);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            uri = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getParcelableExtra("path");
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                idFilePath = uri.getPath();
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+idFilePath);
                imgID.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                String filename;
                filename = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                File imageID1 = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null),  filename.concat(".jpg"));

                FileOutputStream fos;

                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(imageID1);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                uriID1 = Uri.parse(imageID1.getAbsolutePath());

                idChecker1 = "new";
                uriString = uriID1.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: ID1"+uriString);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check logcat for any errors? 
Also did you request the [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)? 
Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` and `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` to the android manifest? See also [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera)

Comment: No errors it is successfully moved to the Camera Activity but no Camera. Yes I have put those permissions

Comment: Indeed there is nothing that would launch a camera app. As taking a picture with the camera app is pretty basic for a programmer you should be able to find an example that works. First try without all those put extras.

Answer (score 0):

From API level 30 package visibility is restricted. So, try adding appropriate query in your `AndroidManifest` file.

```
<manifest package="package-name">
    ...
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```